# Check if a pull request is up to date with the target branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, merge, github-api

Our project is using protected branches and requires the base branch of a PR to be up-to-date with the target branch in order to merge. We are also using Jenkins to build the unmerged head of the PR because the plugin we use will automatically rebuild all open PRs when the target branch changes, which can quickly clog up a pipeline. So, in the case that a PR is opened without being up-to-date with the target branch, we want to be able to stop the Jenkins pipeline right away and notify the committer that they need to merge first.

So, using the GitHub API, I would like to be able to tell if a pull request is up-to-date with the target branch. The closest thing to this seems to be the "mergeable" attribute on a pull request, but that looks like it only indicates whether a safe auto-merge CAN be done, not whether the branch is already up-to-date.

Is there a direct API json tag that can be looked at? If not, is there a simple way to check this manually with git commands?

Comment: [Required Status Checks](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks) have an option to `Require branches to be up to date before merging`. While this doesn't answer the API portion of your question, it may be a valid workflow to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a modern way of doing so

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor A B
```

see [git-merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know whether GitHub exposes this information through their API, but you can detect this manually with Git commands. You want to find what is known as the merge base, and ensure that this commit is the same as the tip of `master` (or whatever your main branch is).

In the form of a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script, it would look something like this:

```sh
if [ $(git merge-base @ master) == $(git rev-parse master) ]
then
  echo "Your branch is up to date."
  exit 0
else
  echo "You need to merge / rebase."
  exit 1
fi
```

If you include this script as a build step, then the exit values should cause Jenkins to fail the job if necessary.

As mentioned in [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934787/2747593), with newer versions of Git you can use the `--is-ancestor` flag for `git merge-base` to simplify it to one command.  The script would then look like this:

```sh
if git merge-base --is-ancestor master @
then
  echo "Your branch is up to date."
  exit 0
else
  echo "You need to merge / rebase."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: you could even use BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH instead of master to make it dynamic

Comment: @Jorge Thanks, that's a good options for Bitbucket; presumably GitHub has something similar.

Comment: Oops, my bad. you right hehe.

Comment: I added echo to get the results: git merge-base --is-ancestor master @ ; echo $?

Comment: In addition, usually Github send to Jenkins the merged branch - so you need to check if the origin branch is updated:  git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/master origin/${ghprbSourceBranch};

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use github API.
Any API that returns the pull request object will have the `mergeable_state` field in it.
If its value is `behind`, that means the base branch is updated after the pull request is created. ie: pull request branch is out of date.

Here's [mergestatestatus](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#mergestatestatus) explanation

If you are handling webhook responses in Jenkings server, most pull request events like, pull request created, edited, closed or issue_comment events will include the `mergeable_state` information in the pull request object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use GitHub's GraphQL API and retrieve the [`mergeStateStatus`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#mergestatestatus) value as others have mentioned. The sample shell script below assumes you already know the pull request's number and have a [GitHub personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

```
# get-merge-state-status.sh example

# $TOKEN should be a defined environment variable

OWN_ORG='IBM'
REPO='data-import'

# get PR number from input
PR_NUMBER=$1

# prepare query with the appropriate parameters
QUERY=`cat <<EOF
{"query": 
    "query {
        repository(owner: \"${OWN_ORG}\", name: \"${REPO}\") {
            pullRequest(number: ${PR_NUMBER}) {
                title
                state
                mergeStateStatus
            }
        }
    }"
}
EOF`

# remove new lines so that the api understands the query
QUERY=$(echo $QUERY|tr -d '\n')

curl_opts=(
 -s
 -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.merge-info-preview+json"
 -X POST 
 -d "$QUERY"
)

# make the api call
JSON=$(curl "${curl_opts[@]}" https://api.github.com/graphql)


STATE=$(echo $JSON | jq -r '.data.repository.pullRequest.state')
M_STATE=$(echo $JSON | jq -r '.data.repository.pullRequest.mergeStateStatus')

echo $STATE $M_STATE
```

Then you can run the script as:

```
[anask@supremedev]$ bash get-merge-state-status.sh 10
OPEN CLEAN
```

Note that if you're using GitHub Enterprise then change the address from `api.github.com` to `api.github.<SRV_NAME>.com`.

Answer (score -1):

`git rev-list` can be used to return the difference between two branches as long as the PR branch has a common point with the target branch (e.g. master):

```
git rev-list --left-right --count  \                                                                 
    origin/dev_develop...$(git branch --show-current) | \                                        
    awk '{print "Behind "$1" - Ahead "$2""}'

# output example: Behind 13 - Ahead 20
```

So you can add the following check with the appropriate exit code:

```
target="origin/master"
source=$(git branch --show-current)

# compare the target branch to the pull request branch
behind=`git rev-list --left-right --count  $target...$source | awk '{print $1}'`

if [[ $behind = 0 ]];
    then
        echo 'Up to date!'
        exit 0
    else
        echo 'Please merge!'
        exit 1
fi
```

If you're using Travis or other CI jobs that don't pull all the commits, perform a `git fetch` before you compare the branches:

```
# fetch the pull request branch's commits
git config remote.origin.fetch \
    +refs/heads/"${source}":refs/remotes/origin/"${source}"
git fetch origin
```

Answer (score -3):

This is a very common problem for people who want to implement a workflow where merge are serialized.

This is something that can be solved using [Mergify](http://mergify.io) easily. It offers exactly what you need via its [strict workflow](http://doc.mergify.io/strict-workflow.html). Mergify takes in charge the update of your out-of-date pull request and order the merge of the valid pull requests for you. We built Mergify to solve exactly this problem in the first place actually!

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the Mergify author)